# Aggregate assignment in VHDL using smaller aggregates

Tags: vhdl, variable-assignment

Is there a way to write something like this:

```
x <= (2 downto 0 => y(2 downto 0), others => y(3));
```

instead of this:

```
x <= (2 => y(2), 1 => y(1), 0 => y(0), others => y(3));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing it exactly as you said? Looks to me like it should work.

Comment: What is the type of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to show declarations. It's possible to answer based on the expectation your second aggregate in an assignment to `x` works.

lasplund's comment on your question that it should work is predicated to IEEE Std 1076-2008 compatibility in which slices in aggregates were added. (See Peter Ashenden and Jim Lewis's book *VHDL 2008 Just the New Stuff*, 6.4 Slices in Aggregates).

Support varies by VHDL tool implementation, usually a command line or configuration option to provide -2008 support.  Previous revisions of the standard only followed your apparently working alternative with single element associations.

See 1076-2008 8.5 Slice names and 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

Without VHDL-2008, you can do:

```
x <= (x'length-1 downto 3 => y(3)) & y(2 downto 0);
```